# python: Deleting NaN-Values in an array with objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I am kinda new to python, but I want to read some data out of a file with python. And my Problem is that there are NaN-Values in the data and I am unable to delete them. It would be also an idea to replace them with a zero.

My data looks like this:

```
>>> data
array(['123.6', 'NaN' , '124.5' , '8463.9' , .... , '764.8'],
      ['NaN', '763.9', ..., 'NaN'] , dtype=object]
```

I created it with numpy array. And my goal is to creape a `np.float` without the NaN-Values. Thus I thought it would be a good idea to create a mask with `np.isnan(data)` but I get the following error

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Then I had an other idea how to solve this problem. I thought about using the `np.setdiff1d(data,NaN)` function and therefor I wanted to create an array with NaN-Values:

```
>>> NaN = np.array([NaN, NaN])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined
```

but I don't managed it to work.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**EDIT I:**

If you want to recreate my Problem:
- I give you the data at the end of the comment.
- my whole code:

```
file = open('data.txt','r')
data = [ ]
for line in (x for x in file if not (x.startswith('#'))):
    line = line.strip().split(' ')
    data.append(line)
data = np.array(data)
```

This code works. But if I try the next step `data = data.astype(np.float)` it isn't working, because of the NaN-Values.

Part of my original data, which I save as an `.txt` file.

```
1564.5  927.5   -33.217633987949434 -75.28690848012765  0.8646  0.8654  0.8041  0.8399  0.816   0.8157  0.8005  0.7783  0.7758  0.3526  0.0023  0.0513  0.0507  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
1565.5  927.5   -33.215517631467705 -75.28691044613586  0.8538  0.8055  0.7497  0.7763  0.7828  0.785   0.7782  0.73    0.7504  0.3455  0.0021  0.0493  0.0478  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
1566.5  927.5   -33.213401274416846 -75.28691239293255  0.8768  0.8702  0.7963  0.8287  0.8233  0.8209  0.7982  0.7617  0.7737  0.3599  0.002   0.0469  0.0512  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
1488.5  928.5   -33.378488511902496 -75.28724058707648  0.8861  0.8839  0.8238  0.8425  0.8199  0.8224  0.8003  0.7847  0.7765  0.3624  0.0023  0.0561  0.0597  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1489.5  928.5   -33.37637213942188  -75.28724401326073  0.8813  0.8479  0.7873  0.8153  0.8422  0.8334  0.8146  0.7521  0.79    0.3608  0.0021  0.0572  0.0584  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1490.5  928.5   -33.374255765947325 -75.2872474202336   0.884   0.8697  0.8102  0.845   0.8455  0.8415  0.8285  0.7883  0.7974  0.359   0.0023  0.0554  0.0576  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1491.5  928.5   -33.37213939148442  -75.28725080799506  0.8901  0.8802  0.8183  0.856   0.8566  0.8435  0.8285  0.7786  0.804   0.3601  0.0024  0.0553  0.057   NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1492.5  928.5   -33.370023016038736 -75.28725417654512  0.8815  0.8607  0.8006  0.8368  0.8314  0.8275  0.8135  0.771   0.7865  0.3536  0.0023  0.0541  0.055   NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1493.5  928.5   -33.367906639615875 -75.28725752588373  0.8751  0.8435  0.7843  0.8148  0.8174  0.8144  0.8019  0.7449  0.7686  0.3536  0.0023  0.052   0.0538  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1494.5  928.5   -33.36579026222143  -75.28726085601092  0.8719  0.8724  0.8177  0.8545  0.8387  0.8299  0.8211  0.7898  0.793   0.3545  0.0023  0.055   0.0586  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1495.5  928.5   -33.363673883860976 -75.28726416692662  0.8701  0.8694  0.8039  0.8428  0.8347  0.835   0.8166  0.7782  0.7856  0.3534  0.002   0.0543  0.0546  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1496.5  928.5   -33.36155750454011  -75.28726745863086  0.8688  0.8537  0.7963  0.8333  0.825   0.829   0.81    0.7709  0.7784  0.3479  0.0019  0.0525  0.0546  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1497.5  928.5   -33.35944112426442  -75.28727073112363  0.8548  0.8283  0.7676  0.8069  0.8027  0.7961  0.7849  0.738   0.7596  0.3399  0.002   0.0513  0.0511  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1498.5  928.5   -33.35732474303949  -75.28727398440489  0.8691  0.828   0.7659  0.8038  0.8106  0.7977  0.7894  0.7406  0.7664  0.3452  0.0022  0.0506  0.0502  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1499.5  928.5   -33.35520836087091  -75.28727721847463  0.8878  0.8503  0.7941  0.8226  0.8437  0.8301  0.8254  0.7611  0.791   0.3579  0.0021  0.0533  0.0563  NaN NaN 63.2476 64.9044 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1500.5  928.5   -33.35309197776428  -75.28728043333282  0.8974  0.8695  0.8044  0.8397  0.8516  0.8445  0.8307  0.7854  0.8033  0.3628  0.0023  0.0575  0.0592  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
1501.5  928.5   -33.350975593725174 -75.28728362897951  0.8998  0.877   0.8148  0.8441  0.8492  0.84    0.8154  0.7692  0.7918  0.3604  0.0021  0.0515  0.0525  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
1502.5  928.5   -33.34885920875918  -75.28728680541461  0.9023  0.8761  0.8141  0.8487  0.8483  0.8415  0.8216  0.7694  0.7926  0.3603  0.002   0.0526  0.0552  9.591876    121.94432   63.2077 64.7261 9.68262 118.91  9.48605 126.374 9.51632 124.666 9.55169 123.097 9.57373 122.254 9.59818 121.403 9.62448 120.563 9.50012 125.52  9.65311 119.719 9.71611 118.056 9.53956 123.598 9.59347 121.561 9.65895 119.555
```

Answer (score 2):

`"NaN"` is a string and that's all it means to Numpy. If you want to have a real nan object you should use `np.nan` (and numpy represents it as `nan`). Also the `np.isnan()` doesn't word for arrays with type object:

```
In [16]: data = np.array([1, 3])

In [17]: np.isnan(data)
Out[17]: array([False, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: data = np.array([1, 3, 'NaN'])

In [19]: np.isnan(data)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0b9ec100cedb> in <module>()
----> 1 np.isnan(data)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

In [20]: data = np.array([1, 3, np.nan])

In [21]: np.isnan(data)
Out[21]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: But the problem is that the data set use NaN instead of nan.

Comment: @Mara So try to load your file with a proper numpy function like [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: I tried it but it says `ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'Pixel-X'` but I searched through the whole data set and didn't find the "b'Pixel-X'" ....

Comment: @Mara Well what's `b'Pixel-X'`? this string cant be converted to float. I think you can also try other functions list `genfromtxt` which have more options for ignoring items.

Comment: I don't know what `b'Pixel-X'` is... I searched through the whole file and found nothing like this.

Comment: @Mara I can't see in either. Maybe you're opening another file? do you execute the code in a same directory as your file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = np.where(data == `NaN`, np.nan, data.astype(float))
```

or even

```
data = data.astype(float)
```

Then you can probably use your other functions.

Testing:

```
a=np.array([['1.2','NaN'],['NaN','4.5']], dtype='object')

a
Out[347]: 
array([['1.2', 'NaN'],
       ['NaN', '4.5']], dtype=object)

a.astype(float)

Out[348]: 
array([[ 1.2,  nan],
       [ nan,  4.5]])
```

Trying to replicate the error:

```
a=np.array([['1.2','NaN'],['NaN','4.5','NaN']], dtype='object')

a
Out[350]: array([['1.2', 'NaN'], ['NaN', '4.5', 'NaN']], dtype=object)

a.astype(float)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  a.astype(float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: The second recommendation I used for code without NaN and it works. With NaN  I get the following error message `data = data.astype(float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: And I get the same error for the first recommendation, too.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] then, when I test with similar input to what you have both work.

Comment: Waaait a second.  Do you have a ragged array (i.e. do your rows have a different numbers of elements)?  That error isn't from `.astype`, it's an error thrown from a dimension mismatch.

Comment: my rows should have the same number of elements. and with other data without NaNs from the same source it works. i edit my post with a example.

Comment: Just because they should have the same number of elements, doesn't mean they do.  If `np.array(data)` gives you a `dtype=object` array, you probably have a ragged list.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of lists of strings. Try casting to float.

```
for i,row in enumerate(data):
    for j,x in enumerate(row):
        data[i][j]=float(x)
```

Comment: If I try this I get `>>> data = [float(x) for x in data]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' `